# An error occurred when executing Randomwalk2dmobility in NS3

Tags: ns-3

I am a newbie to NS3. I want to understand the execution status of handover in the Randomwalk2d module and visualize it. The default is two Ue and two enb, but errors will always occur during execution. Can anyone help me solve the problem? 
This is my code link:https://drive.google.com/file/d/163NQOyvs0bTh2J4P9_vpS4Y7iqocB3HJ/view?usp=sharing
When I execute the command : `./waf --run scratch/lte_handover --visualize`, the following error  appear

`../scratch/lte_handover.cc:In funtion 'int main(int, char**)':`
`../scratch/lte_handover.cc:296:78: error: expected ')' before ';' token`
`"Bounds",RectangleValue (Rectangle (0,2000,0,2000)));`
                                                    `^`
Build failed
->task in 'lte_handover' failed with exit status 1 (run with -v to display more information)
Follow the instructions to enter the command :`./waf --run scratch/lte_handover -v`, and the following information appears

- Several tasks use the same identifier. Please check the information on 
  https://waf.io/apidocs/Task.html?highlight=uid#waflib.Task.Task.uid

- object 'SuidBuild_task'(
  {task 139759060979784: SuidBuild_task  -> }) defined in 'tap-creator'
- object 'SuidBuild_task'(
  {task 139759060980008: SuidBuild_task  -> }) defined in 'tap-creator'
- object 'SuidBuild_task'(
  {task 139759065638504: SuidBuild_task  -> }) defined in 'tap-creator'

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have an extra `)` in that line above. You are not closing this command as you commented all the lines

```cpp
ueMobility.SetPositionAllocator ("ns3::RandomRectanglePositionAllocator",  // <-- close
ueMobility.SetMobilityModel ("ns3::RandomWalk2dMobilityModel","Bounds", RectangleValue (Rectangle (0,2000,0,2000)));
```